# How to autopopulate div class form

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, html

I have an Autoresponder email form on my page.

Below is part of the code of that form, for the email to be entered by customer:

```
<div id = "af-form-45" class = "af-form" >
   <div id = "af-body-45" class = "af-body af-standards" > 
       <div class = "af-element" > 
          <label class = "previewLabel" for = "awf_field-57" > </label> 
          <div class="af-textWrap">
             <input class="text" id="awf_field-57" type="text" name="email" value="Form 555" tabindex="500" onfocus=" if (this.value == 'Form 555') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='Form 555';} " / >
          </div>
          <div class="af-clear"> </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The prepopulated email value in that form is 'Form 555'. Meaning that is someone lands on the page and sees the form, it already has the value of 'Form 555'

What I need to do is to pre-populate the field not with 'Form 555', but with certain value, which I get from running a Javascript in my header (that Javascript is long, so I'm not including it here).

But for example, if I put the below code on the page, it will return a certain email address (which I need to be prepopulated in the form).

```
<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("email")</script>
```

So I need to do the same, but inside that div class form - this email address to be added instead of 'Form 555' prepopulated value
Thanks!

Comment: `$('#awf_field').val(formData.display("email"));`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple, is there something else you are struggling with?

Change

```
<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("email")</script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#awf_field').val(formData.display("email"))
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, Nix! Should it be like the below ? value="$('#awf_field').val(formData.display("email"))"

Comment: @user3173723 I don't understand your question ?

Comment: Thanks, @Nix. well, I cannot change the whole Div class code. Is there any way I could replace XXXXXX in the 

<div class="af-textWrap"><input class="text" id="awf_field" type="text" name="email" value="XXXXXXXXX"  />

with something, that would put email instead of XXXXXXX ?

Comment: Thats what the code above does... you add it as a script block, or include a js file that does what you need.  I dont understand what you are asking...

Comment: Sorry, Here's the full code I have, @Nix:

<div id="af-form-45" class="af-form"><div id="af-body-45"  class="af-body af-standards">
<div class="af-element">
<label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-57"></label>
<div class="af-textWrap"><input class="text" id="awf_field-57" type="text" name="email" value="Form 555" tabindex="500"  onfocus=" if (this.value == 'Form 555') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='Form 555';} " />
</div><div class="af-clear"></div>
</div>


So I don't get it, where do I add your code to insert email instead of Form 555 :(

Comment: no, @Nix, your updated code doesn't work... I need only 'email' in name="email" to be substituted...

<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("email")</script>

this code is giving me value if I add it to the page. So I just need that value to end up in the value='email' field...

Comment: Too many comments, update your question and explain what you need.

Comment: thanks, @Nix. Rephrased the question. Tried to make it as clear as possible

Answer (score 0):

You can set val throu

```
$("#awf_field").val(formData.display("email"));
```